# Cannot access NSArray content from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, nsarray

I know that this will sound like a stupid question and a lot of people will now start telling me that I need to read apple documentation on how properties work, googling for similar issues and closing this as duplicate, etc ... I did some search, tried reading apple documentation, but still can't figure out what is wrong with my code and will appreciate some help to the point ...

I have NSMutable array defined in respective .h and .m of PrefMySpotsViewCtrl class like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mySpotsArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mySpotsArray;

@synthesize mySpotsArray;
```

When I NSLog this array from the same class like this:

```
NSLog(@"in class: %@", mySpotsArray);
```

All works well. I am trying to NSLog this array from another class like this:

```
PrefMySpotsViewCtrl *PrefMS = [[PrefMySpotsViewCtrl alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", [PrefMS mySpotsArray]);
```

It shows as empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Edit ...

I initialise the array like this:

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    mySpotsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

return self;
}
```

Adding, deleting objects like this:

```
/-----------------------------------------
- (IBAction)addSpot:(id)sender
{
[mySpotsArray addObject:[[MySpots alloc]init]];
[mySpotsTable reloadData];

[self saveMySpots];
}




//-----------------------------------------
- (IBAction)deleteSpot:(id)sender
{
NSInteger row = [mySpotsTable selectedRow];
[mySpotsTable abortEditing];
if (row !=-1)
{
    [mySpotsArray removeObjectAtIndex: row];
}

[mySpotsTable reloadData];

[self saveMySpots];
 }
```

Comment: Does the `init` method put anything in the array? If not then that is why it is empty. Also the first example uses the class variable, use `self.mySpotsArray` instead to test.

Comment: Yes it does and I can access array content from within the same class.

Comment: How do you initialize the array?

Comment: **Where** in `PrefMySpotsViewCtrl` do you put things into the array?

Comment: Edited to provide code for array initialisation and adding / deleting objects

Comment: replace mySpotsArray -> self.mySpotsArray in class

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
PrefMySpotsViewCtrl *PrefMS = [[PrefMySpotsViewCtrl alloc] init];
```

...creates a new object.  It will not have any `MySpots` objects in its array until something calls `addSpot:`.  The fact that you may have a different `PrefMySpotsViewCtrl` object with `MySpots` in **its** array doesn't affect the one you've just created.

Comment: I thought the above line of code is a "link" to the Class where array is located .... as I am not doing alloc init for array itself .... am I missing the point?

Comment: That line creates a new object.  Each object created as an instance of the `PrefMySpotsViewCtrl` class has its own `mySpotsArray` that, in turn, gets created during the `init` method.

Comment: ok, understood, so how can I access the array without that line?

Comment: Someplace you must have created your original `PrefMySpotsViewCtrl` object...the one that is responding to the add/delete requests.  Either that one has to pass the array to this new class that wants to use it or the new class has to request it from the existing `PrefMySpotsViewCtrl`.  Exactly how depends on how those objects are created in your app.

Comment: Sorry Phillip, I feel that you are pointing me to the right direction but can't figure out where is my mistake. I have 'addSpot' method in 'PrefMySpotsViewCtrl' class as described above.

Comment: I think perhaps you're confusing classes and objects.  These are object methods so they only relate to an object that is created with `alloc` (or some other creation method) or that is built from your xib or storyboard.  The code in the method exists for all the objects in the class, but the data that an object contains (as properties or instance variables) -- its state -- is unique to that object.

Comment: Where you were trying to access the array...what creates that object?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Creating objects and accessing the array from the same class works ok. I need to continue creating the objects of the array from the same class but accessing it from another class.

Comment: I was trying to ask how the object from "another class" is created (the object that contains the `PrefMySpotsViewCtrl *PrefMS = [[PrefMySpotsViewCtrl alloc] init];` line).  That is, what object/method allocates it?